# Add data to stream in Flutter not working

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am trying to add data to my stream on flutter when I click a button (send button, kind of chat funcionality).
However, despite of I am adding data to my streamController with sink, the stream does not get updated with the new data.

Declarations:

```
`StreamController<List<dynamic>> msgStreamController =
    StreamController<List<dynamic>>.broadcast();
Stream<List<dynamic>> stream = msgStreamController.stream;
List<dynamic> msgList = [];`
```

this is the part when I add data when I press the send button:

```
`                      msgList.add(chatMessageModelRecord);
                      setState(() {
                        msgStreamController.sink.add(msgList);
                        
                      });`
```

This is the part where I initialize my streambuilder and I display my data coming from the stream function:

`````
`class _MessagesStreamState extends State<MessagesStream> {
  Stream<List<dynamic>>? streamMessages;
  @override
  void initState() {
    stream = fetchMessagesFromBack4App(
        widget.usermail, widget.usermailTo, widget.title);

    super.initState();
  }


    ```
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return const Center(
                    child: Text('No connection!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)));
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                debugPrint('ConnectionState.waiting with data');
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              case ConnectionState.active:
                debugPrint('ConnectionState.active with data');
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    // reverse: true,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
                    // itemCount: widget._allMessagesContainedInTheStream.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
    ```
    
    ````


the function I use to fetch messages from my database:

    Stream<List<dynamic>> fetchMessagesFromBack4App(
      String usermail,
      String usermailTo,
      String dogName,
      //List<ChatMessageModel> messagesList,
      // StreamController<ChatMessageModel> streamcontroler
    ) async* {
      final queryBuilder = QueryBuilder(ParseObject('MessagesSender'))
        ..whereEqualTo('sender', usermail)
        ..whereEqualTo('receiver', usermailTo)
        ..whereEqualTo('dogname', dogName)
        ..orderByAscending('date');
      final response = await queryBuilder.query();
      if (response.results == null) {
        //fetchMessagesFromBack4App(usermailTo, usermail, dogName, streamcontroler);
        final queryBuilder = QueryBuilder(ParseObject('MessagesSender'))
          ..whereEqualTo('sender', usermailTo)
          ..whereEqualTo('receiver', usermail)
          ..whereEqualTo('dogname', dogName)
          ..orderByAscending('date');
        final response = await queryBuilder.query();
    
        if (response.results != null) {
          msgStreamController.sink.add(response.results!.toList() as List<ParseObject>);
          yield response.results!.toList() as List<ParseObject>;
          
        }
        /////////////////////////
      } else {
        msgStreamController.sink.add(response.results!.toList() as List<ParseObject>);
        yield response.results!.toList() as List<ParseObject>;
        
      }
    }

The streamcontroller does not come with the new data.
`````

Comment: And `fetchMessagesFromBack4App` is continuing to receive more items somehow?

Comment: that function gets all the messages from DB and display them once you enter the chat. I inlcude my stream controller inside it which is a global definition. You can see it above how this function works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me it seems like you are overriding where the `stream` object should take it's values from. First stream depends on the `streamController` -> `(Stream<List<dynamic>> stream = msgStreamController.stream;)` but later in the `initState` you override it to: `stream = fetchMessagesFromBack4App( widget.usermail, widget.usermailTo, widget.title);`. But in the function itself, you keep updating `streamController`. This doesn't provide any new data in the `stream` tho.. because it's no longer depending on the stream from `streamController`.

Comment: but then how do I add my messages from my database? Somehow I need to update streamController inside my function, right?